# Recover Windows 8 from recovery partition without OS

Tags: windows-8, recovery-partition

I have tablet with originally came with 'Windows 8 with Bing".

I deleted the OS, but recovery partition is still present. I tried but with a different edition of Windows (e.g. core or pro) can't recover from recovery partition with "Reset your PC" option. And there isn't an image for Windows 8 with Bing. So as you may guess I just want a originally licensed OS. Any way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you check if Core would activate online or via phone when installed? If it doesn't, you might need to contact the manufacturer.

Comment: No it won't. I think there is not any way to recover my os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I backed up "install.wim" file from recovery partition. (Installed an OS to do this.) Created a bootable Win 8.1 USB disk with an original iso and changed install.wim file with which I backed up. Installed and it's activated itself. So it seems licensing info in install.wim file. And it read the key from UEFI and activated. This trick will be usefull for many case.